# pass value from dropdown to html actionlink mvc4 razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to pass a value from a drop down list to an existing link, however nothing seems to work:

index.cshtml:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "MyDownload", null, new { @class = "button" })&nbsp;&nbsp;
@Html.DropDownList("schools", "-- All Schools --")&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

in my SchoolsController:

```
public FileContentResult MyDownload(string school="")
{
    List1<>
    List2<>

    var vals = 
         from list1
         join list2
         from
         select new {
             };

    if(school ! ="")
    {
        vals.where(x.list2.schools==school).tolist(); **// I get this error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**
    }    
}
```

Something I can do easily in other languages, I find learning C# MVC takes forever.

Comment: @sza: I find it to be quite alive and flexible; You must have been on a [picnic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error).

Comment: @BradChristi Of course not. I know how to use it. But since using MVVM and javascript can do everything I want, why i have to bother to use a view engine...

Comment: Then why bother to comment at all @sra... If this is something you don't use, don't bother to comment. You are not helping, to say the least...  Menew, a thought might be to use jQuery to check the selection on the change Event.  MVC is different but I've found a lot of times it's easier than web forms were.

Comment: thanks guys, i am learning c# mvc and i know the question might sound basic to most of you, it is not for a newbie. thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jQuery to monitor the change Event on your dropdownlist.  Now, I'm not entirely sure if you're trying to change the text that is used for the link or the actual href of the link.  Below I've created some code to change both.

View

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#schools").change(function () {
        var selection = $("#schools").val();
        var link = $("#Download");

        //Change text
        link.text(selection);

        //Change href
        link.attr("href", "linkHref" + selection)
    });
});
```

It will look something like this, pending what you're wanting to do with your link and dropdownlist's selection.

Comment: nice, so i can include jquery in asp.net? cool. all i have to include is the <script> tags? so when a user selects from the drop down, i want it to use the htmlaction link, which i will provide using your jquery code. thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can add jQuery into asp.net.  Just place it within your script tags.